# How to add Error Markers in Visual Studio 2010 (C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting, intellisense

I seem to have lost the default error markers(highlighting), those curly wavy red lines that appear in the TextEditor of VS2010 IDE (for C++) when you type something that isn't syntactically correct (syntax errors, non existing overloads, ...etc).

Is there a way to reset them to default settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Go to tools -> options and under `Environment`, select the `Fonts and Colors` node.

Choose `Text Editor` from `Show the settings for` and in the `Display items` listbox look up the item `Syntax Error` and fix the setting you want or use the `Use Defaults` button on top of the same options form.

[image]